# Execute animation in angular 4 on click only not on page load

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-animations

I have a input field which displays on page load.

[image]

On click of search i'm displaying result.

[image]

On click of hide your search parameter i'm hiding search input and on click of show i'm showing it.

[image]

But the problem is that as i have applied slide in on search input field which load on page load it is animating. I want to add animation only when i click on hide or show your search parameter link.

This is what i have tried so far

```
<div class="row seven-cols" *ngIf="showSearch" [@slideIn]>
            <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Store#">
                    </div>
                    <!-- Search Button -->
    <button type="button"[disabled]="isValidStoreId || !storeMod"
                            (click)="search(storeMod)">
                            {{componentContents.searchButton}}
                        </button>
                </div>
```

This is the code to toggle search

```
<span class="filterPipe"><a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="showSearch = !showSearch" class="toggleTxt">{{ showSearch == true ? 'Hide' : 'Show' }} {{componentDetails.searchToggleHead}}</a></span>
```

this is the code for my slide in/out animation

```
 animations: [
    trigger('slideIn', [
      state('*', style({ 'overflow-y': 'hidden' })),
      state('void', style({ 'overflow-y': 'hidden' })),
      transition('* => void', [
        style({ height: '*' }),
        animate(250, style({ height: 0 }))
      ]),
      transition('void => *', [
        style({ height: '0' }),
        animate(250, style({ height: '*' }))
      ])
    ])
  ]
```

Please suggest me how to handle this?

Comment: Instead of using `void` and `*` states, use named states. This way, it does nothing when appearing, and you can apply the names states on click.

Comment: Can you please give me a example of that as i'm new to angular animations

Comment: [The documentation](https://angular.io/guide/animations) is there for you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `* => void` and `void => *` which are equivalent to `:enter` and `:leave`. They're fired every time the element appears/disappears (using `*ngIf`).

To control the animation and fire it just on click, you should use custom transitions (`active => inactive` and `inactive => active` in my code below).

Change your animation like this:

```
animations: [
  trigger('slideIn', [
    state('active', style({ 'overflow-y': 'hidden' })),
    state('inactive', style({ 'overflow-y': 'hidden' })),
    transition('active => inactive', [
      style({ height: '*' }),
      animate(250, style({ height: 0 }))
    ]),
    transition('inactive => active', [
      style({ height: '0' }),
      animate(250, style({ height: '*' }))
    ])
  ])
]
```

Then in your HTML, remove `*ngIf` and use the animation like this:

```
<div class="row seven-cols" [@slideIn]="showSearch?'active':'inactive'">
```

I haven't tested the code. But it should work. Let me know if there's any error.

### If you have to use `*ngIf`

If using `*ngIf` is necessary, you can have another variable and switch it on and off on animation done. Like this:

```
(@slideIn.done)="animDone($event)"
```

And

```
animDone(e: AnimationEvent) => {
  if (e.toState === 'active') showSearchNgIf = true;
  else if (e.toState === 'inactive') showSearchNgIf = false;
}
```

Comment: Without *ngIf do i need to set showSearch active/inactive on click of link?

Comment: Without ngif it is not hiding search bar

Comment: @user1881845 yes same as your code, you need to set showSearch active/inactive on click of link. Also thanks for reporting